# Can a stealth recorder app be created on android which can record everything the mic captures for like 12 hours?

Tags: android

i am a c# .net developer and i also know some java like servlets and jsp. I want to develop an app where i can start the recording by tapping on the app and after 10-12 hours i can stop the recording and view whatever file was created on the sd card. I dont have much knowledge in android but if i get some idea where to start. Like which classes to researched on google. I also want the app to run in background. Even if it shows in running services it wont matter. It just shouldnt show notifications while recording. 1 last thing i want to ask is that is it feasible for a 8 gb card where like 6-7 gb is free to hold 10-12 hours of recording. Audio shouldnt be of very bad quality. Plz.I came to know from google that i need to create a service in order to achieve this. But can some1 be more precise. Reply me as soon as possible. Thanx in advance. I forgot to mention I also have a rooter phone.

Comment: Get to work son!  Let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: Break your problem down into discreet steps and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: What's your problem with standard Android audio recorder app? That is shows notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what do you mean by stealth? To whom?

Generally you need to create a foreground service that will run in background for 12 hours and will keep your device awake using [`PowerManager.WakeLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) (not every device will have enough battery). This service will utilize [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class to record audio.

Services tutorials: [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html), [Creating background service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

**EDIT:**

Also, [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) is an implementation of a background service from CommonsWare that keeps your device awake. Easy to use out-of-box and will handle half of your problems.

Comment: Can the service which uses PowerManager.WakeLock be created without any activity initially?? I mean I can implement AudioRecord in a day or two. I just want to start away asap. By stealth i mean if I leave my fone anywhere it shouldnt show any notification coz my fone maybe around people who know my lock and how much I change it I will have to tell them even if i dont want to. But these people are complete noobs so they cant even view my running apps. So i just want a notification free app and shouldnt show in the taskmanager. Thx for giving me a kick start. Thx a lot

Comment: `WakeLock` is just a mechanism that notifies OS that your service needs some device resources (e.g. Wi-Fi or CPU) and OS should not turn them off while your service is running.

`Can the service which uses PowerManager.WakeLock be created without any service initially??` Can a service be created without service? What do you mean?

Comment: i meant activity instead of service. I already edited my comment as soon as i read it. Thx its starting to look easier now.

Comment: Activity generally should not be used for long-running operations (you can user `AsyncTask` for tasks around 30 seconds). It will be much harder to prevent OS from stopping your activity as non-responsive. Services are intended for long-running tasks. Start with a service, it's not that hard.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a reference to wakeful service implementation. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: VoteUp requires 15 reputation :( is there any other way?? Any other way to say thanks ??